# Solve a system of nonlinear equations with conditions

Tags: python, system, sympy, equation

I want to solve the following system of nonlinear equations. Is it possible to put condition that all variables are greater or equal zero and all parameters are positive? The variables are (x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2 ) and others are just parameters.

And is Maple better to solve this system than sympy?

```
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex=True)
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp


x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2 = sp.symbols('x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2')
N, c1, c2, c3, c4 = sp.symbols('N, c1, c2, c3, c4')
r1, r2, r3, r4 = sp.symbols('r1, r2, r3, r4')
f11, f21, f31, f41 = sp.symbols('f11, f21, f31, f41')
f12, f22, f32, f42 = sp.symbols('f12, f22, f32, f42')
eta11, eta12, eta13, eta14 = sp.symbols('eta11, eta12, eta13, eta14')
eta21, eta22, eta23, eta24 = sp.symbols('eta21, eta22, eta23, eta24')
eta31, eta32, eta33, eta34 = sp.symbols('eta31, eta32, eta33, eta34')
eta41, eta42, eta43, eta44 = sp.symbols('eta41, eta42, eta43, eta44')
epsilon1, epsilon2, K11, K22 = sp.symbols('epsilon1, epsilon2, K11, K22')
omega1, omega2, gamma12, g12 = sp.symbols('omega1, omega2, gamma12, g12')
beta11, beta21, beta31, beta41 = sp.symbols('beta11, beta21, beta31, beta41')
beta12, beta22, beta32, beta42 = sp.symbols('beta12, beta22, beta32, beta42')

F2 = x1 * (r1 * (1 - (eta11 * x1 + eta12 * x2 + eta13 * x3 + eta14 * x4) / N) - \
   f11 * y1 - f12 * y2)
F3 = x2 * (r2 * (1 - (eta21 * x1 + eta22 * x2 + eta23 * x3 + eta24 * x4) / N) - \
   f21 * y1 - f22 * y2)
F4 = x3 * (r3 * (1 - (eta31 * x1 + eta32 * x2 + eta33 * x3 + eta34 * x4) / N) - \
   f31 * y1 - f32 * y2)
F5 = x4 * (r4 * (1 - (eta41 * x1 + eta42 * x2 + eta43 * x3 + eta44 * x4) / N) - \
   f41 * y1 - f42 * y2)

F6 = y1 * (-epsilon1 * (1 + (y1 + omega2 * y2) / K22) - g12 * y2 + beta11 * f11 * x1 + \
   beta21 * f21 * x2 + beta31 * f31 * x3 + beta41 * f41 * x4)

F7 = y2 * (-epsilon2 * (1 + (omega1 * y1 + y2) / K11) +gamma12 * g12 * y1 + \
   beta12 * f12 * x1 + beta22 * f22 * x2 + beta32 * f32 * x3 + beta42 * f42 * x4)              

equ = (F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7)
sol = nonlinsolve(equ, x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2)   

print(sol)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a polynomial system and we can put into standard form with

```
In [2]: equ = [eq.as_numer_denom()[0].expand() for eq in equ]                                                                                                 

In [3]: for eq in equ: pprint(eq)                                                                                                                             
                                                2                                             
-N⋅f₁₁⋅x₁⋅y₁ - N⋅f₁₂⋅x₁⋅y₂ + N⋅r₁⋅x₁ - η₁₁⋅r₁⋅x₁  - η₁₂⋅r₁⋅x₁⋅x₂ - η₁₃⋅r₁⋅x₁⋅x₃ - η₁₄⋅r₁⋅x₁⋅x₄
                                                               2                              
-N⋅f₂₁⋅x₂⋅y₁ - N⋅f₂₂⋅x₂⋅y₂ + N⋅r₂⋅x₂ - η₂₁⋅r₂⋅x₁⋅x₂ - η₂₂⋅r₂⋅x₂  - η₂₃⋅r₂⋅x₂⋅x₃ - η₂₄⋅r₂⋅x₂⋅x₄
                                                                              2               
-N⋅f₃₁⋅x₃⋅y₁ - N⋅f₃₂⋅x₃⋅y₂ + N⋅r₃⋅x₃ - η₃₁⋅r₃⋅x₁⋅x₃ - η₃₂⋅r₃⋅x₂⋅x₃ - η₃₃⋅r₃⋅x₃  - η₃₄⋅r₃⋅x₃⋅x₄
                                                                                             2
-N⋅f₄₁⋅x₄⋅y₁ - N⋅f₄₂⋅x₄⋅y₂ + N⋅r₄⋅x₄ - η₄₁⋅r₄⋅x₁⋅x₄ - η₄₂⋅r₄⋅x₂⋅x₄ - η₄₃⋅r₄⋅x₃⋅x₄ - η₄₄⋅r₄⋅x₄ 
                                                                                                                               2
K₂₂⋅β₁₁⋅f₁₁⋅x₁⋅y₁ + K₂₂⋅β₂₁⋅f₂₁⋅x₂⋅y₁ + K₂₂⋅β₃₁⋅f₃₁⋅x₃⋅y₁ + K₂₂⋅β₄₁⋅f₄₁⋅x₄⋅y₁ - K₂₂⋅ε₁⋅y₁ - K₂₂⋅g₁₂⋅y₁⋅y₂ - ε₁⋅ω₂⋅y₁⋅y₂ - ε₁⋅y₁ 
                                                                                                                                   2
K₁₁⋅β₁₂⋅f₁₂⋅x₁⋅y₂ + K₁₁⋅β₂₂⋅f₂₂⋅x₂⋅y₂ + K₁₁⋅β₃₂⋅f₃₂⋅x₃⋅y₂ + K₁₁⋅β₄₂⋅f₄₂⋅x₄⋅y₂ - K₁₁⋅ε₂⋅y₂ - K₁₁⋅g₁₂⋅γ₁₂⋅y₁⋅y₂ - ε₂⋅ω₁⋅y₁⋅y₂ - ε₂⋅y₂
```

SymPy will try to solve this using the Groebner basis but it takes a long time to compute that:

```
In [4]: groebner(equ, [x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2]) # Not sure how long this takes
```

I expect though that even if it does complete the result will not admit analytic solutions because solving will likely lead to polynomials of greater than order 4.

If you replace all of the parameters with concrete rational numbers then it is possible that a solution could be found but otherwise in terms of arbitrary symbols (`r3` etc) I don't expect that a closed form solution will exist - if that's true then it doesn't matter whether you use Maple or SymPy or anything else.

EDIT: I now see what your system is. Each equation is of the form `x1 * (a*x1 + b*x2 + ...)` so it's a linear equation multiplied by one of the unknowns. That means that there are two possibilities: `x1 = 0` or the linear equation is satisfied. So one solution is that `x1 = x2 = ... = 0` and then there is another where none are zero. With 6 unknowns there are 64 possible solutions except some might not satisfy the non-negativity assumptions. You can find them all with

```py
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex=True)
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp


x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2 = sp.symbols('x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2', nonnegative=True)
N, c1, c2, c3, c4 = sp.symbols('N, c1, c2, c3, c4', positive=True)
r1, r2, r3, r4 = sp.symbols('r1, r2, r3, r4', positive=True)
f11, f21, f31, f41 = sp.symbols('f11, f21, f31, f41', positive=True)
f12, f22, f32, f42 = sp.symbols('f12, f22, f32, f42', positive=True)
eta11, eta12, eta13, eta14 = sp.symbols('eta11, eta12, eta13, eta14', positive=True)
eta21, eta22, eta23, eta24 = sp.symbols('eta21, eta22, eta23, eta24', positive=True)
eta31, eta32, eta33, eta34 = sp.symbols('eta31, eta32, eta33, eta34', positive=True)
eta41, eta42, eta43, eta44 = sp.symbols('eta41, eta42, eta43, eta44', positive=True)
epsilon1, epsilon2, K11, K22 = sp.symbols('epsilon1, epsilon2, K11, K22', positive=True)
omega1, omega2, gamma12, g12 = sp.symbols('omega1, omega2, gamma12, g12', positive=True)
beta11, beta21, beta31, beta41 = sp.symbols('beta11, beta21, beta31, beta41', positive=True)
beta12, beta22, beta32, beta42 = sp.symbols('beta12, beta22, beta32, beta42', positive=True)

F2 = (r1 * (1 - (eta11 * x1 + eta12 * x2 + eta13 * x3 + eta14 * x4) / N) - \
   f11 * y1 - f12 * y2)
F3 = (r2 * (1 - (eta21 * x1 + eta22 * x2 + eta23 * x3 + eta24 * x4) / N) - \
   f21 * y1 - f22 * y2)
F4 = (r3 * (1 - (eta31 * x1 + eta32 * x2 + eta33 * x3 + eta34 * x4) / N) - \
   f31 * y1 - f32 * y2)
F5 = (r4 * (1 - (eta41 * x1 + eta42 * x2 + eta43 * x3 + eta44 * x4) / N) - \
   f41 * y1 - f42 * y2)

F6 = (-epsilon1 * (1 + (y1 + omega2 * y2) / K22) - g12 * y2 + beta11 * f11 * x1 + \
   beta21 * f21 * x2 + beta31 * f31 * x3 + beta41 * f41 * x4)

F7 = (-epsilon2 * (1 + (omega1 * y1 + y2) / K11) - gamma12 * g12 * y1 + \
   beta12 * f12 * x1 + beta22 * f22 * x2 + beta32 * f32 * x3 + beta42 * f42 * x4)              


equ = ((x1, F2), (x2, F3), (x3, F4), (x4, F5), (y1, F6), (y2, F7))

from itertools import product
for eqs in product(*equ):
    sol = solve(eqs, [x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2])
    pprint(sol)
```

That gives:

```
$ python t.py 
{x₁: 0, x₂: 0, x₃: 0, x₄: 0, y₁: 0, y₂: 0}
[]
[]
⎧                                      ε₂⋅(K₁₁⋅(K₂₂⋅g₁₂ + ε₁⋅ω₂) - K₂₂⋅ε₁)                ε₁⋅(-K₁₁⋅ε₂ + K₂₂⋅(K₁₁⋅g₁₂⋅γ₁₂ + ε₂⋅ω₁
⎨x₁: 0, x₂: 0, x₃: 0, x₄: 0, y₁: ───────────────────────────────────────────────, y₂: ──────────────────────────────────────────
⎩                                ε₁⋅ε₂ - (K₂₂⋅g₁₂ + ε₁⋅ω₂)⋅(K₁₁⋅g₁₂⋅γ₁₂ + ε₂⋅ω₁)      ε₁⋅ε₂ - (K₂₂⋅g₁₂ + ε₁⋅ω₂)⋅(K₁₁⋅g₁₂⋅γ₁₂ + ε

))   ⎫
─────⎬
₂⋅ω₁)⎭
⎧                          N               ⎫
⎨x₁: 0, x₂: 0, x₃: 0, x₄: ───, y₁: 0, y₂: 0⎬
⎩                         η₄₄              ⎭
⎧                            N⋅ε₂⋅(K₁₁⋅f₄₂ + r₄)                 K₁₁⋅r₄⋅(N⋅β₄₂⋅f₄₂ - ε₂⋅η₄₄)⎫
⎪x₁: 0, x₂: 0, x₃: 0, x₄: ──────────────────────────, y₁: 0, y₂: ───────────────────────────⎪
⎨                                      2                                       2            ⎬
⎪                         K₁₁⋅N⋅β₄₂⋅f₄₂  + ε₂⋅η₄₄⋅r₄              K₁₁⋅N⋅β₄₂⋅f₄₂  + ε₂⋅η₄₄⋅r₄⎪
⎩                                                                                           ⎭
⎧                            N⋅ε₁⋅(K₂₂⋅f₄₁ + r₄)          K₂₂⋅r₄⋅(N⋅β₄₁⋅f₄₁ - ε₁⋅η₄₄)       ⎫
⎪x₁: 0, x₂: 0, x₃: 0, x₄: ──────────────────────────, y₁: ───────────────────────────, y₂: 0⎪
⎨                                      2                                2                   ⎬
⎪                         K₂₂⋅N⋅β₄₁⋅f₄₁  + ε₁⋅η₄₄⋅r₄       K₂₂⋅N⋅β₄₁⋅f₄₁  + ε₁⋅η₄₄⋅r₄       ⎪
⎩                                                                                           ⎭
... (continues)
```

The empty solutions `[]` correspond to the cases that are known not to satisfy the non-negativity requirement.

Comment: I have 52 parameters in the system . I nondimensionalized the system and the number reduced to 40 ,still many. Matlab was able to solve it in terms of parameters but without imposing the condition. Sympy couldn't (waited one day),Sagemath couldn't either.I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @user2653663 Thanks!I am impressed by how fast the code gives the solution. Could you explain the code little bit ,what the loop do actually? Yes , matlab gave me 64 solution which was not what I wanted because I don’t need negative solutions

Comment: It tries every combination of the unkown being zero or not and in each case tries to solve for the other unknowns.

Comment: If I add a constant s_i to the righ hand side of F2,F3,F4,F5 after the brackets then zero is not a solution and we need to use nonlinsolve again. Here I just assumed that s_i is zero but it is not

Comment: I've given you a carefully crafted solution for the equations as presented. If you make them more complicated then my original points about the possible nonexistence of analytic solutions stand.

Comment: The code has been running for some hours and it doesn't seem that it will finish. Until now it didnt give the all easy combination (y1=0,y2=0,all x's equal zero except one).

Answer (score 0):

You can add assumptions to your symbols. The documentation is slightly confusing to me about which solvers obey these assumptions, but it seems like from [the docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#nonlinsolve) that `nonlinsolve` does obey these:

```
x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2=sp.symbols('x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2', nonnegative=True)
N,c1,c2,c3,c4=sp.symbols('N,c1,c2,c3,c4', positive=True)
```